# How to create a link between the attributes of two tables?

Tags: php, database

I am creating a database that allows me to save the data to a json online.
I have problems connecting the teams between two tables, the table structure Fixture is as follows:

[image]

Table Design teams:

[image]

My problem is that I want to load the Fixtures of a given team, for example, I want to load the fixtures of Wolfsburg. Now I'm thinking of being able to exploit the attribute CODE in its teams table, but I do not have this attribute in the table Fixtures and would not know how to connect it as the Fixtures are downloaded from a JSON as you see in the image.
The json presents a link between the team's fixture but concerns the relative links to each team and not a foreign key.
How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Can you match by name?

Comment: how much data do you have thus far in these tables? If it's not too much at this stage a little redesigning of the tables might be called for

Comment: The data are really too many so I need an effective system to recognize the teams and load the parameters of a team X from another table, in this case fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

Your tables only has `homeTeamName` and `name` as common value. You can try to do join on them, but it will be slow and not reliable. I don't see any other way as there is no ID in each table.

Comment: It's really a big problem, you might create a third table containing all teams and somehow tie a ID to these two?

Comment: @HaroldFinch Have ID in second table (PK, Auto Increment) and when writing data to first table find ID by name, add team_id column

Comment: Ok for the second table I realized that I have to enter an ID as a primary key, but do not understand how to connect this ID with the second table, you may be more clear?